# Problemas con Transacción SQL Server y ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando transacciones para enviar datos al SQL de la siguiente forma:

```
public string nvBeneficio(Beneficio objBeneficio)
    {
        string mensaje = "";
        cn = conexion.getConexion();
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("NV_BENEFICIO", cn, tr);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nomBeneficio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objBeneficio.nomBeneficio;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@desBeneficio", SqlDbType.Text).Value = objBeneficio.descripcion;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objBeneficio.idUsuario;
            try
            {

               int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               tr.Commit();
                mensaje=   "Se a creado " + i + " nuevo beneficio !";


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mensaje = e.Message;
                tr.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {


                cn.Close();

            }
        }
        return mensaje;
    }
```

El procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROC NV_BENEFICIO(@nomBeneficio VARCHAR(255),
@desBeneficio text,
@idUsuario int
)
AS
    IF ( CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM IH_BENEFICIOS WHERE NOM_BENEFICIO=@nomBeneficio)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO IH_BENEFICIOS VALUES(@nomBeneficio, @desBeneficio, GETDATE(),@idUsuario )
    END
    ELSE
        RAISERROR(  '¡El beneficio llamado %s ya existe en inventario !', 11, 1, @nomBeneficio);

GO
```

Lo que pasa es que me parece que se está ejecutando 2 veces la transacción porque me da un mensaje que dice "¡El beneficio llamado Cena ya existe en inventario !", o sea, el mensaje de error desde la base de datos, pero el beneficio sí se agrega.

En la llamada al procedimiento hago esto:

```
protected void btnGuardarBeneficio_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Beneficio objBeneficio = new Beneficio();
        string mensaje = "¡ Beneficio No registrado !";
        dr = objNegocio.infoMaster(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Rows[0];
        objBeneficio.nomBeneficio = txtNombreBeneficio.Value;
        objBeneficio.descripcion = txtDescripcionBeneficio.Value;
        objBeneficio.idUsuario = int.Parse(dr["ID_USUARIO"].ToString());
        mensaje = objNegocio.nvBeneficio(objBeneficio);


        CatalogoBeneficios();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alerta", "<script> alert('" + mensaje + "'); </script>", false);

    }
```

La capa de negocio es la que dice objNegocio y es sólo esto:

```
public string nvBeneficio(Beneficio objBeneficio)
    {
        return cnProcedimientos.nvBeneficio(objBeneficio);
    }
```

Agradezco la pronta ayuda !

---

El problema se debía al navegador, estaba usando Opera, lo probé con Firefox y me funciona bien.

Comment: Aclaro que prové el procedimiento en SQL y sí funciona bien, lo que me hizo sospechar que el problema está en el código.

Comment: a tu if cambialo por exists te quedaria if exists(SELECT * FROM IH_BENEFICIOS WHERE NOM_BENEFICIO=@nomBeneficio)  ... se entiende mejor asi. El rollback no es necesario porque ni siquiera se inserto el registro, osea no necesitas una transaccion solo ejecucion del SP

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el evento `btnGuardarBeneficio_ServerClick` puedes validar que ingresa solo una vez ? porque puede que se este ejecutando la accion dos veces

Comment: tu transaccion es innecesaria, solo ejecuta el store procedure.

Comment: En qué caso sería necesaria usar una transacción ? porque en este caso la uso para evitar que otro usuario añada un beneficio al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Al poner puntos de interrupción me di cuenta que está entrando al Try (guardando el beneficio) pero brinca al Catch, devolviendome el mensaje de error, como si el procedimiento almacenado terminara ejecutándose con el raiserror lo cual no pasa cuando lo pruebo desde el SQL Management Studio.